# How long took a person to get the break even investing since 2000 in MSCI WORLD INDEX?

Tags: stocks, investing, index-fund

I read in another forum that a person who invest before the Dot-com bubble (2000) took 15 years to get the break-even. Basically only in 2014 or 2015 he starts to gain money.

This seems wrong, but i don't have any data to prove that. How can i simulate an investment in MSCI WORLD INDEX since 2000 and check how long took to get the break-even?

Any idea about that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He is wrong.

Using Total Return (Reinvesting Dividend), from the peak in December 1999, it only took 6 years to recover.

[image]

You can check the data for free [here](http://www.msci.com/products/indexes/performance.html?chart=regional&priceLevel=0&scope=R&style=C&asOf=Apr%252014,%25202015&currency=15&size=36&indexId=2591). Make sure you choose "Gross Index Level".

ACWI Index is Developed Markets + Emerging Markets. 
World Index is Developed Markets only.

Comment: What tool do you use to create the chart? thanks for the answer

Comment: Click "here". There is a link.

Comment: ok, i don't have flash. I will try in another browser. thanks.

Comment: Technically that would be six years, wouldn't it?  12/31/1999 -> 12/31/2005?